# js regex between strings with repeated characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match on the contents of some code between the strings `var` and `);`

I'm currently using:

```
var([^)]+)\);
```

And this matches, except for when another closing bracket appears elsewhere in the text. So,

```
var (this does match);
var (this) doesn't match but should);
```

Regex example [here](https://regex101.com/r/MezcGu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simply this one if I understood fine what you want to match:

```
/var(.*);/
```

Comment: This will need g flag

Comment: yes, that works! its always the simple answers that are best.